Closet Rod Built Into Drywall?
I have been doing some renovations in an old bedroom here at my place and was wondering if anyone has seen a closet with the rod built into the drywall. What would be my best bet at removing this as there is nothing to unscrew? Maybe a reciprocating saw?

Please post a photo

What's your question? Almost any saw will cut a closet rod. What caused you to pause and post this on the internet? (You haven't' even told us what the rod is made of or where the other end goes.)

You'll have to patch drywall anyway if you are removing the rod, so cut around it to see where it's actually fastened, and how.
Then remove it and patch the drywall where it was removed.
